# Strange Javascript is returned when using php script to periodically check LAMP server homepage

Tags: javascript, php, cron, lamp

I have a cron job setup that runs a php script that checks my server every 5 minutes using file_get_contents() and sends me an email if something is wrong. Twice now I have gotten emails that contain the same javascript snippet instead of the homepage that it is requesting. The script is run from a different webhost.

The page that the script is receiving instead is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>  </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function bredir(a, b, c, d, e, ldr, ifc) {
            var h, i, j;
            var f = 0;
            var g = 0;
            var k = false;
            var l = false;
            var m = [
                [300, 250, false],
                [250, 250, false],
                [240, 400, false],
                [336, 280, false],
                [180, 150, false],
                [468, 60, false],
                [234, 60, false],
                [88, 31, false],
                [120, 90, false],
                [120, 60, false],
                [120, 240, false],
                [125, 125, false],
                [728, 90, false],
                [160, 600, false],
                [120, 600, false],
                [300, 600, false],
                [300, 125, false],
                [530, 300, false],
                [190, 200, false],
                [470, 250, false],
                [720, 300, true],
                [500, 350, true],
                [550, 480, true],
                //YouTube:
                [560, 315, true],
                [640, 360, true],
                [853, 480, true],
                [1280, 720, true],
                //Vimeo:
                [400, 300, true],
                [500, 281, true],
                //Hulu:
                [480, 270, true],
                [512, 288, true],
                //metacafe:
                [440, 248, true],
                [460, 284, true],
                [540, 304, true],
                [600, 338, true],
                //Other dimensions (metacafe, myspace video, yahoo video, break.com, ustream, vevo, justin.tv, etc):
                [210, 120, true],
                [400, 300, true],
                [425, 350, true],
                [425, 360, true],
                [435, 251, true],
                [435, 271, true],
                [500, 300, true],
                [525, 295, true],
                [575, 324, true],
                [620, 389, true],
                [624, 351, true],
                [630, 381, true],
                [640, 385, true],
                [650, 368, true],
                [1000, 562, true],
                [1000, 563, true],
                [1000, 564, true]
            ];
            if (typeof window.innerHeight == "number") {
                g = window.innerHeight;
                f = window.innerWidth;
            } else if (typeof document.body.offsetHeight == "number") {
                g = document.body.offsetHeight;
                f = document.body.offsetWidth;
            }
            for (var n = 0; n < m.length; n++) {
                j = m[n];
                h = Math.abs(f - j[0]);
                i = Math.abs(g - j[1]);
                if (top != self) {
                    ifc = 1;
                } else {
                    ifc = 0;
                };
                if (h <= 2 && i <= 2) {
                    k = true;
                    l = j[2]
                }
            }
            if(f === 0 && g === 0){
                return;
            }
            if ((a != "www.facebook.com" && a != "platform.twitter.com") && (k || f < 100 && f !== 0 || g < 100 && g !== 0)) {
                if (l && self == parent) {
                    return;
                }
                return "/b" + "anner.php?w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&d=" + a + "&url=" + b + "&ref=" + c + "&view=" + d
            } else if ((a == "www.facebook.com" || a == "platform.twitter.com") && (f >= 250 && g >= 60) && (k || f < 100 && f !== 0 || g < 100 && g !== 0)) {
                if (l && self == parent) {
                    return;
                }
                return e + "&w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&ldr=" + "b" + "&ifc=" + ifc;
            } else if ((a == "www.facebook.com" || a == "platform.twitter.com") && (f < 250 || g < 60) && (k || f < 100 && f !== 0 || g < 100 && g !== 0)) {
                if (l && self == parent) {
                    return;
                }
                return "/b" + "anner.php?w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&d=" + a + "&url=" + b + "&ref=" + c + "&view=" + d;
            } else {
                return e + "&w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&ifc=" + ifc;
            }
        }
        function bdetect() {
            var loc = bredir(
                'mydomain.com',
                'mydomain.com',
                '',
                'error',
                '/main?wc=EWJoExdxBAVDBxduBAoL&url=mydomain.com'
            );

            if(typeof loc === 'undefined') {
                self.close();
                return;
            }

            location.replace(loc);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="bdetect()" style="margin: 0px;">
    <noscript>
        <iframe frameborder="0" src="/main?wc=EWJoExdxBAVDBxduBAoL&amp;url=mydomain.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </noscript>
</body>
```

I've found this code around the web with various errors, but usually it was with iis errors and I'm not really sure why I would ever get this instead of the homepage.

I searched the entire webserver for anything resembling this and found nothing.

A slightly modified version of the php code is:

```
$mail_these_people = "asdf@mydomain.com,asdf2@mydomain2.com"; 
$site_foot_code = 'Specific code to look for'; 

$mysite_url = "http://mydomain.com"; 
$mysite_site_title_code = "More specific txt to look for"; 

$mysite_code = file_get_contents($mysite_url); 

if(strpos($mysite_code,$mysite_site_title_code)===false || strpos($mysite_code,$site_foot_code)===false) 
{ 
        echo "mysite Down\n"; 
        if(mail($mail_these_people,"mysite not showing up correctly!","This is what we got instead:\n\n".$mysite_code)) 
                echo "Mail sent successfully\n"; 
        else 
                echo "Mail failded!\m"; 
} 
else 
        echo "mysite Up\n";
```

Comment: Is it possible that your ISP sometimes redirects requests to other sites? This sounds like there is something injected between your request and the target site.

Comment: when you run the php directly does it download the correct page?

Comment: Patrick: It works fine when I browse to the page in a browser and every other time that this checking script runs. I've only had the javascript show up twice with months of the script running.

Comment: Wolfgang: The script is being run on a lamp vps that I rent from a hosting company. I can see the connection and the successful 200 in the apache access log for the times when I get the javascript response.

Comment: The JS looks like some sort of banner engine, connected to Facebook and Twitter, does that mean anything to you? Otherwise it would be a bit worrying that your server apparently responds with stuff you have no idea about.

Comment: The facebook and twitter stuff means nothing to me. Since the /main and the /banner.php links don't exist on my server, I can't see this code doing any harm, but all the dimension code and the iframe make it look like it's some sort of proxy interfering. I was hoping someone on here would have seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same thing and it appears to be a redirection page issued by OpenDNS in the event that the domain name is not found. Here are the headers captured by Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 5444
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 13:36:22 GMT
Server: OpenDNS Guide
```